# How to store arbitrary values in a recursive structure or how to build a extensible software architecture?

Tags: haskell, architecture, functional-programming

I'm working on a basic UI toolkit and am trying to figure out the overall architecture.

I am considering to use [WAI's structure for extensibility](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/wai-3.0.1.1/docs/Network-Wai.html#g:1). A reduced example of the core structure for my UI:

```
run :: Application -> IO ()
type Application = Event -> UI -> (Picture, UI)
type Middleware = Application -> Application
```

In WAI, arbitrary values for Middleware are saved [in the vault](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vault-0.3.0.3/docs/Data-Vault-Lazy.html#t:Vault). I think that this is a bad hack to save arbitary values, because it isn't transparent, but I can't think of a sufficient simple structure to replace this vault to give every Middleware a place to save arbitrary values.

I considered to recursively store tuples in tuples:

```
run :: (Application, x) -> IO ()
type Application = Event -> UI -> (Picture, UI)
type Middleware y x = (Application, x) -> (Application, (y,x))
```

Or to only use lazy lists to provide a level on which is no need to separate values (which provides more freedom, but also has more problems):

```
run :: Application -> IO ()
type Application = [Event -> UI -> (Picture, UI)]
type Middleware = Application -> Application
```

Actually, I would use a modified lazy list solution. Which other solutions might work?

Note that:

- I prefer not to use lens at all.
- I know `UI -> (Picture, UI)` could be defined as `State UI Picture` .
- I'm not aware of a solution regarding monads, transformers or FRP. It would be great to see one.

Comment: You say that you prefer not to use lenses, but this is exactly the kind of problem that lenses solve well

Comment: Note that the design goals for WAI are likely quite different than what you're going for. I tend to agree with Gabriel here, and that's as someone who *doesn't* use lens very often.

Comment: @MichaelSnoyman Actually, i don't know what i want. Something gets in and out and controlling its in-outs is enough for the minimalistic UI. The Middleware definition seems sufficient. The Application is a core of the UI. The usual user don't write the Application. That is a different purpose and maybe not the best approach, but the issue about the Middleware is there.

Comment: @GabrielGonzalez i tried the usual lens libraries once. There are too big and complex. A smaller lens library is okay i guess. How would lens solve this?

Comment: Oh and the `run` function is just a dummy. It shouldn't look that way.

Comment: @Vektorweg Check out `lens-family-core` and `lens-family`, which are much smaller lens libraries that are compatible with the larger `lens` library.  I'll give an answer for how to use them later today.

Answer (score 1):

Lenses provide a general way to reference data type fields so that you can extend or refactor your data set without breaking backwards compatibility.  I'll use the `lens-family` and `lens-family-th` libraries to illustrate this, since they are lighter dependencies than `lens`.

Let's begin with a simple record with two fields:

```
{-# LANGUAGE Template Haskell #-}

import Lens.Family2
import Lens.Family2.TH

data Example = Example
    { _int :: Int
    , _str :: String
    }

makeLenses ''Example
-- This creates these lenses:
int :: Lens' Example Int
str :: Lens' Example String
```

Now you can write `State`ful code that references fields of your data structure.  You can use `Lens.Family2.State.Strict` for this purpose:

```
import Lens.Family2.State.Strict

-- Everything here also works for `StateT Example IO`
example :: State Example Bool
example = do
    s <- use str     -- Read the `String`
    str .= s ++ "!"  -- Set the `String`
    int += 2         -- Modify the `Int`
    zoom int $ do     -- This sub-`do` block has type: `State Int Int`
        m <- get
        return (m + 1)
```

The key thing to note is that I can update my data type, and the above code will still compile.  Add a new field to `Example` and everything will still work:

```
data Example = Example
    { _int  :: Int
    , _str  :: String
    , _char :: Char
    }

makeLenses ''Example
int  :: Lens' Example Int
str  :: Lens' Example String
char :: Lens' Example Char
```

However, we can actually go a step further and completely refactor our `Example` type like this:

```
data Example = Example
    { _example2 :: Example
    , _char     :: Char
    }

data Example2 = Example2
    { _int2 :: Int
    , _str2 :: String
    }

makeLenses ''Example
char     :: Lens' Example Char
example2 :: Lens' Example Example2

makeLenses ''Example2
int2  :: Lens' Example2 Int
str2  :: Lens' Example2 String
```

Do we have to break our old code?  No!  All we have to do is add the following two lenses to support backwards compatibility:

```
int :: Lens' Example Int
int = example2 . int2

str :: Lens' Example Char
str = example2 . str2
```

Now all the old code still works without any changes, despite the intrusive refactoring of our `Example` type.

In fact, this works for more than just records.  You can do the exact same thing for sum types, too (a.k.a. algebraic data types or enums).  For example, suppose we have this type:

```
data Example3 = A String | B Int

makeTraversals ''Example3
-- This creates these `Traversals'`:
_A :: Traversal' Example3 String
_B :: Traversal' Example3 Int
```

Many of the things that we did with sum types can similarly be re-expressed in terms of `Traversal'`s.  There's a notable exception of pattern matching: it's actually possible to implement pattern matching with totality checking with `Traversal`s, but it's currently verbose.

However, the same point holds: if you express all your sum type operations in terms of `Traversal'`s, then you can greatly refactor your sum type and just update the appropriate `Traversal'`s to preserve backwards compatibility.

Finally: note that the true analog of sum type constructors are `Prism`s (which let you build values using the constructors in addition to pattern matching).  Those are not supported by the `lens-family` family of libraries, but they are provided by `lens` and you can implement them yourself using just a `profunctors` dependency if you want.

Also, if you're wondering what the `lens` analog of a newtype is, it's an `Iso'`, and that also minimally requires a `profunctors` dependency.

Also, everything I've said works for reference multiple fields of recursive types (using `Fold`s).  Literally anything you can imagine wanting to reference in a data type in a backwards-compatible way is encompassed by the `lens` library.